# No default binding for component instance "d0 : or2". # (Component port "out1" is not on the entity.)

Tags: vhdl, digital-logic

I am trying to build an xor gate in VHDL using structural code. I have built the same gate using other methods to compare the output using a testbench.

Here is the xor_structural.vhdl file. I built the and,or, and nand myself. I do not think they need to go in a separate file since it compiles just fine. The file and the test bench compile without issue but I can not run a simulation.

The test bench and other simulations work great, but when I try to run a simulation I get the following error.

I think there is something about the structural code that I am missing.

```
vsim work.antivalenz_tb
# vsim work.antivalenz_tb 
# ** Note: (vsim-3813) Design is being optimized due to module recompilation...
# ** Warning: [1] /afs/tu-berlin.de/home/k/kekellerncsu/irb-ubuntu/digsys/aufgaben/01/antivalenz-Struktureben.vhd(51): (vopt-3473) Component instance "u0 : nand2" is not bound.
# ** Warning: [1] /afs/tu-berlin.de/home/k/kekellerncsu/irb-ubuntu/digsys/aufgaben/01/antivalenz-Struktureben.vhd(52): (vopt-3473) Component instance "u1 : nand2" is not bound.
# ** Warning: [1] /afs/tu-berlin.de/home/k/kekellerncsu/irb-ubuntu/digsys/aufgaben/01/antivalenz-Struktureben.vhd(53): (vopt-3473) Component instance "u2 : nand2" is not bound.
# ** Warning: [1] /afs/tu-berlin.de/home/k/kekellerncsu/irb-ubuntu/digsys/aufgaben/01/antivalenz-Struktureben.vhd(54): (vopt-3473) Component instance "u3 : nand2" is not bound.
# ** Warning: [1] /afs/tu-berlin.de/home/k/kekellerncsu/irb-ubuntu/digsys/aufgaben/01/antivalenz-Struktureben.vhd(55): (vopt-3473) Component instance "u4 : nand2" is not bound.
# ** Warning: [1] /afs/tu-berlin.de/home/k/kekellerncsu/irb-ubuntu/digsys/aufgaben/01/antivalenz-Struktureben.vhd(56): (vopt-3473) Component instance "u5 : nand2" is not bound.
# ** Error: /afs/tu-berlin.de/home/k/kekellerncsu/irb-ubuntu/digsys/aufgaben/01/antivalenz-Struktureben.vhd(51): No default binding for component instance "u0 : nand2".
#  (Component port "out1" is not on the entity.)
# ** Warning: [1] /afs/tu-berlin.de/home/k/kekellerncsu/irb-ubuntu/digsys/aufgaben/01/antivalenz-Struktureben.vhd(57): (vopt-3473) Component instance "u6 : nand2" is not bound.
# ** Warning: [1] /afs/tu-berlin.de/home/k/kekellerncsu/irb-ubuntu/digsys/aufgaben/01/antivalenz-Struktureben.vhd(59): (vopt-3473) Component instance "d0 : or2" is not bound.
# ** Warning: [1] /afs/tu-berlin.de/home/k/kekellerncsu/irb-ubuntu/digsys/aufgaben/01/antivalenz-Struktureben.vhd(60): (vopt-3473) Component instance "d1 : or2" is not bound.
# ** Warning: [1] /afs/tu-berlin.de/home/k/kekellerncsu/irb-ubuntu/digsys/aufgaben/01/antivalenz-Struktureben.vhd(61): (vopt-3473) Component instance "d2 : or2" is not bound.
# ** Warning: [1] /afs/tu-berlin.de/home/k/kekellerncsu/irb-ubuntu/digsys/aufgaben/01/antivalenz-Struktureben.vhd(62): (vopt-3473) Component instance "d3 : or2" is not bound.
# ** Warning: [1] /afs/tu-berlin.de/home/k/kekellerncsu/irb-ubuntu/digsys/aufgaben/01/antivalenz-Struktureben.vhd(63): (vopt-3473) Component instance "d4 : or2" is not bound.
# ** Warning: [1] /afs/tu-berlin.de/home/k/kekellerncsu/irb-ubuntu/digsys/aufgaben/01/antivalenz-Struktureben.vhd(64): (vopt-3473) Component instance "d5 : or2" is not bound.
# ** Error: /afs/tu-berlin.de/home/k/kekellerncsu/irb-ubuntu/digsys/aufgaben/01/antivalenz-Struktureben.vhd(59): No default binding for component instance "d0 : or2".
#  (Component port "out1" is not on the entity.)
# ** Warning: [1] /afs/tu-berlin.de/home/k/kekellerncsu/irb-ubuntu/digsys/aufgaben/01/antivalenz-Struktureben.vhd(65): (vopt-3473) Component instance "d6 : or2" is not bound.
# ** Error: /afs/tu-berlin.de/home/k/kekellerncsu/irb-ubuntu/digsys/aufgaben/01/antivalenz-Struktureben.vhd(67): No default binding for component instance "x1 : and2".
#  (Component port "out1" is not on the entity.)
# ** Warning: [1] /afs/tu-berlin.de/home/k/kekellerncsu/irb-ubuntu/digsys/aufgaben/01/antivalenz-Struktureben.vhd(67): (vopt-3473) Component instance "x1 : and2" is not bound.
# Optimization failed
# Error loading design
```

Xor_struktur.vhdl 
    entity and2 is
    port (A, B : in bit;
       Y    :  out bit);
    end entity and2;

```
architecture logic of and2 is
begin
   Y <= (A and B);
end architecture logic;

entity or2 is
port(A, B : in  bit;
Y    : out bit);
end entity or2;

architecture logic of or2 is
begin
   Y <= A or B;
end architecture logic;

entity nand2 is
port (A, B : in bit;
Y    :  out bit);
end entity nand2;   

architecture logic of nand2 is
begin
Y <= not(A and B);
end architecture logic; 

entity antivalenz_struktur is
port ( a , b : in bit_vector(0 to 3) ;
      Y : out bit ) ;
end entity antivalenz_struktur ;

architecture struktur of antivalenz_struktur is
   component and2
        port (a, b: in bit;
            out1: out bit);
   end component;
   component nand2
        port (a, b: in bit;
            out1: out bit);
   end component;
   component or2
        port (a, b: in bit;
            out1: out bit);
   end component;
signal s0,s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,s6,s7,nand_out,a0,a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,or_out:bit;
begin   
   U0: nand2 port map (a(0),b(0),s0);
   U1: nand2 port map (a(1),b(1),s1);
   U2: nand2 port map (a(2),b(2),s2);
   U3: nand2 port map (a(3),b(3),s3);
   U4: nand2 port map (s0,s1,s4);
   U5: nand2 port map (s2,s3,s5);
   U6: nand2 port map (s4,s5,nand_out);

   D0: or2 port map (a(0),b(0),a0);
   D1: or2 port map (a(1),b(1),a1);
   D2: or2 port map (a(2),b(2),a2);
   D3: or2 port map (a(3),b(3),a3);
   D4: or2 port map (a0,a1,a4);
   D5: or2 port map (a2,a3,a5);
   D6: or2 port map (a4,a5,or_out);

   X1: and2 port map (nand_out,or_out,Y);
end architecture struktur;
```

Test Bench file

```
entity antivalenz_tb is 
end antivalenz_tb;

architecture behavior of antivalenz_tb is
    signal a, b : bit_vector (0 to 3);
    signal Y_Dataflow : bit;
    signal Y_Logic: bit;
    signal Y_Behavior: bit;
    signal Y_Structure: bit;

begin 
    dut: entity work.antivalenz_datenfluss(datenfluss)
    port map(a => a,
            b => b,
            Y => Y_Dataflow);
    dut1: entity work.antivalenz_logic(logic)
    port map(a => a,
            b => b,
            Y => Y_Logic);
    dut2: entity work.antivalenz_verhalten(behavior)
        port map(a => a,
                b => b,
                Y => Y_Behavior);
    dut3: entity work.antivalenz_struktur(struktur)
         port map(a => a,
                 b => b,
                 Y => Y_Structure);           
   a <= "0000",
          "1111" after 10 ns,
          "1010" after 20 ns,
          "0101" after 30 ns,
          "1100" after 40 ns;
   b <= "0000",
        "1111" after 10 ns,
        "0101" after 20 ns,
        "1010" after 30 ns,
        "0011" after 40 ns;
end behavior;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your architecture for `antivalenz_struktur` has component declarations with "out1" as the name of the output but the entities have an output called "Y" in their port lists. You need to make the components match the entities since you are using traditional entity instantiation in that architecture.

Comment: @user3120471 - note that the error message you posted as the question title suggested this very error. Sometimes error messages are less than helpful, but in this case, it got it right.